# How to remove the first 2 rows using zipwithindex using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two headers in the file. have to remove them. i tried with zipwithindex. it will assign the index from zero onwards. But its showing error while performing filter condition on it.

```
val data=spark.sparkContext.textFile(filename)
val s=data.zipWithIndex().filter(row=>row[0]>1) --> throwing error here
```

Any help here please.

```
    Sample data:
===============
    sno,empno,name --> need to remove
    c1,c2,c3 ==> need to remove
    1,123,ramakrishna
    2,234,deepthi

Error: identifier expected but integer literal found
       value row of type (String,Long) does not take type parameters.
       not found: type <error>
```

Comment: 1) Post the error you are facing 2) You don't access tuples with `[]`

Comment: @sinanspd hi, i have added the error as well. can you help here

Comment: See the second point I made. That is not how you access the elements of a Tuple. The correct syntax can be found in the documentation

Answer (score -1):

If you have to remove rows, you can use row_num and remove rows easily by filter row_num>2.